# Impossible to change AVD storage size

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I'm trying to create an AVD with Android 7 (arm image as I'm on a m1 Mac mini) with at least 3gb of internal storage.

While creating the AVD I put the parameters as I want them:
[image]

under the newly created AVD properties, the partition size is like expected:
[image]

but when launching the emulator (both quick launch and cold startup), this setting seems like ignored:
[image]

Sometimes it even says "47.06MB of 1.03GB used", but when opening the submenu the total storage size remains always 533MB.

---

I've already tried to:

- delete and re-create various AVDs, with different hardware profiles
- create a new AVD with an android 11 image (but it didn't event startup, it got stuck on a white screen)
- edit the same AVD with different storage sizes

It seems that only the memory and the heap sizes are correctly changing.

---

My android studio version:

```
Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-212.5712.43.2112.8609683, built on May 18, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 12.3.1
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 8
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true, debugger.watches.in.variables=false, ide.balloon.shadow.size=0
Non-Bundled Plugins: Rider UI Theme Pack (0.10.1), Dart (212.5744), com.markskelton.one-dark-theme (5.6.0), com.intellij.plugins.vscodekeymap (212.3116.29), com.github.copilot (1.1.27.1708), com.wakatime.intellij.plugin (14.0.6), org.jetbrains.kotlin (212-1.7.0-release-281-AS5457.46), io.flutter (68.1.2)
```

I'm using a m1 Mac mini with macOS 12.3.1.

---

Do anyone have (or had) this problem?

---